# Shopify - How to make google analytics load after page load?

Tags: google-analytics, shopify

I am working on shopify project for fist time. My Task is to make google analytics load after a page load. Is it doable? if Yes will it impact on analytic behavour?

Comment: use advance custom solution for lazy loading of the script the are added by {{content_for_header}} tag

Comment: Thanks for response but i didn't get it. can you please explain a little more @Onkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Google Tag Manager and triggering the Analytics tag on page load.

This is not recommended because you may have lost sessions compared to having it run when the GTM loads and consequently less reliable metrics.